# Call Function From Another Component in Angular

Tags: angular, visible, custom-function

Maybe my question is simple but I couldn't fix it.
I have two component. First;

### form.component.ts

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

@Component({
  selector: 'cui-nt-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss'],
})
export class NtFormComponent {

  showForm: boolean = false

  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDownForm.bind(this), false)
  }

  public setVisibleForm() {
    console.log('Form Showing');
    this.showForm = true 
  }

  setHiddenForm() {
    this.showForm = false
  }

  handleKeyDownForm(event: any) {
    if (this.showForm) {
      const key = event.keyCode.toString()
      if (key === '27') {
        this.setHiddenForm()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### form.component.html

```
<div class="d-inline-block mr-4">
  <!-- <button nz-button (click)="setVisibleForm()" nzType="primary">Primary Buttonn</button> -->
  <div class="liveForm" [ngClass]="{'liveformVisible': showForm}">
    <button class="close" type="button" (click)="setHiddenForm()">
      <i class="icmn-cross"></i>
    </button>
    <h5>test form</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

### form.component.scss

```
....
.liveformVisible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
....
```

When I place this component alone and trigger the button, it works fine. However, when I call it in another component, the function works but the display does not appear. The other component I call the function is ;

### dynamic.component.ts

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { NtFormComponent } from 'src/app/components/layout/Forms/form.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'kit-antd-table-dynamic',
  templateUrl: './dynamic.component.html',
  styles: [
    `
      .components-table-demo-control-bar {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
      }

      .nz-form-item {
        margin-right: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }

    `,
  ],
})
export class KitAntdTableDynamicComponent implements OnInit {
  showForm: boolean = false

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private formComponent:NtFormComponent
     ){}
 ....    
  formVisible(){
    this.formComponent.setVisibleForm();
  }
 ....
}
```

### dynamic.component.html

```
<a (click)="formVisible()">Action</a>
```

I am using console.log ('form showing') to test that the function works in form.component.ts. this works but the form is not visible. What is the problem I don't see? Thanks

Comment: Have you put formComponent here? `./dynamic.component.html`

Comment: formComponent attached on the layout. Is it necessary to specify here? how should I do?

Comment: put `<cui-nt-form></cui-nt-form>` in the template for `KitAntdTableDynamicComponent `

Comment: Also I would remove logic for showing/hiding from child component and decide in the parent component when show or hide child component/form

Comment: it give me : '' 'cui-nt-form' is not a known element "

Comment: So you are saying that  `<cui-nt-form></cui-nt-form>` already placed on  layout component template? If so you probably need to create service which will be the bridge between components. I'm not sure how it's possible to inject component in the constructor.